# Storage Allocation for register storage class in C?

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

"Storage for a register storage class variable is allocated each time the control reaches the block in which it is present." is this statement true or false ?

Comment: This feels strangely like an exam question. Almost like you just copied it verbatim. I mean, why phrase it in such a peculiar manner?

Answer (score 4):

Neither. C does not specify the manner of allocation of `register` variables - except you aren't allowed to take their address. It only specifies that access to the variable should be "as fast as possible". When the allocation takes place is an implementation-detail of the compiler.

The `register` keyword is to be regarded as obsolete, since compilers nowadays are much better than programmers at determining what should be placed in registers. Don't use it.